# Python selenium and captcha

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a scraping bot which I want to stop whenever it encounters a captcha, so not to annoy the websites. But selenium can't find it

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='recaptcha-anchor']")
```

This is the xpath chrome gave me.

**ERROR**

> NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='recaptcha-anchor']"}

Any ideas why this does not work?

Comment: Chrome given xpath could be very generic, you may need to look into the html and actually understand the basic syntax of xpath, and better make it more specific, grabbing what you actually want

Comment: Okay, do you have any link to where I could learn a bit more about this?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Comment: BTW, I just noticed your `xpath` is already pretty specifc as it has `@id=...`, so why doesn't it work?

Comment: Just gives me the following error: NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='recaptcha-anchor']"}

Comment: Did you look into the html? What's the url?

Comment: Yeah I did, the element is the following: <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinnerAnimation" role="presentation"></div>

Answer (score 14):

AFAIK, captcha usually located inside an [`iframe`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), so you can try to switch to `iframe` before searching for required element:

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@src, "recaptcha")]')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='recaptcha-anchor']")
```

If you need to switch back from `iframe`:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: You are a god damn genius!

Comment: One small extra question, how do I change the frameback?

Comment: What do you mean *frameback*? Do you mean how can you switch back from `iframe`? Check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

For byPass The reCAPTCHAv2 is within an <iframe..> so you have to:

- Pick the Captchav2 page and define `URL`.
- Induce WebDriverWait for the desired frame to be available and switch to it.
- Induce WebDriverWait for the desired element to be clickable.

  ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

   driver.get(URL)

   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor']")))
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.recaptcha-checkbox-border"))).click()
  ```