# Clicking on a button using selenium [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am opening a URL and trying to click on the `Search` button described here below:

```
<td class="th-sa-tb-bt">
    <span class="th-bt-up">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="th-bt th-bt-text-em" onclick="thBtMgr.click(this);return htmlbSL(this,2,'J22_MNQ_LOP_V1WR_SEARCH_BTN:SEARCH','0')" onmousedown="thBtMgr.press(this,event);" onfocusout="thBtMgr.unpress(this);" onfocus="thSaveKbFocus(this);" oncontextmenu="return false;" ondragstart="return false;" id="J22_MNQ_LOP_V1WR_SEARCH_BTN" title="Search">
            <span class="th-bt-span">
                <b class="th-bt-b">Search</b>
            </span>
        </a>
    </span>
    <span class="th-bt-spacer">
        <!-- -->
    </span>&nbsp;
    <span class="th-bt-up">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="th-bt th-bt-text" onclick="thBtMgr.click(this);return htmlbSL(this,2,'J22_MNQ_LOP_V1WR_CLEAR_BTN:\x23Exit\x23_CLEAR','0')" onmousedown="thBtMgr.press(this,event);" onfocusout="thBtMgr.unpress(this);" onfocus="thSaveKbFocus(this);" oncontextmenu="return false;" ondragstart="return false;" id="J22_MNQ_LOP_V1WR_CLEAR_BTN" title="Clear">
            <span class="th-bt-span">
                <b class="th-bt-b">Clear</b>
            </span>
        </a>
    </span>
    <span class="th-bt-spacer">
        <!-- -->
    </span>&nbsp;
    <span class="th-bt-up">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="th-bt th-bt-text" onclick="thBtMgr.click(this);return htmlbSL(this,2,'J22_MNQ_LOP_V1WR_BtnReset:RESET','0')" onmousedown="thBtMgr.press(this,event);" onfocusout="thBtMgr.unpress(this);" onfocus="thSaveKbFocus(this);" oncontextmenu="return false;" ondragstart="return false;" id="J22_MNQ_LOP_V1WR_BtnReset" title="Reset">
            <span class="th-bt-span">
                <b class="th-bt-b">Reset</b>
            </span>
        </a>
    </span>
    <span class="th-bt-spacer">
        <!-- -->
    </span>
</td>
```

Here when I copy the xpath for the `search` button element `J22_MNQ_LOP_V1WR_SEARCH_BTN` it gives me timeout error.

Here is the code :

```
import time
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("<URL>")
time.sleep(10)

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="J22_MNQ_LOP_V1WR_SEARCH_BTN"]'))
)
element.click()
```

I tried with `XPATH` and `ID` also along with this increased time wait to check if the exception that I get that resolves or not, but unfortunately nothing works, can anybody help here?

Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vanishka\Desktop\test2\.py", line 18, in <module>
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 'J22_MNQ_LOP_V1WR_SEARCH_BTN'))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Added iframe Html :

```
<div id="Uiframecontainer" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
      <iframe name="UiApplicationFrame" id="UiApplicationFrame" frameborder="0" title="Uiframeapp" scrolling="no" src="/zzp(ZT1RelV5TkRJd05EWmZYMTlmT0ROZk1qUmZBSkQ2NW81V0h0aUdvOHBZZWk5ZzFnPT0=)/bc/bsp/zzp/crm_ui_frame/main.htm?zzx-client=001&amp;zzx-language=EN&amp;zzx-domainRelax=min&amp;zzzrole=zzfdecs" style="display: block; visibility: visible;"></iframe></div>

      <frame src="/zzx/bc/bsp/zzx/crmcmp_hdr/bspwdapplication.do?zzx-client=001&amp;zzx-language=EN&amp;zzx-domainRelax=min&amp;zzxrole=zzfedcs" name="HeaderFrame" id="HeaderFrame" title="" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onload="thtmlbSetOnloadFrameEvents(event, this)">
```

Comment: why are you waiting for this element to be clickable? is it initially loaded un-clickable then dynamically made clickable later?

Comment: I am not sure about that but waiting also should work ?

Comment: try removing the waiting lines making it click it directly

Comment: Tried with this `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="J22_MNQ_LOP_V1WR_SEARCH_BTN"]').click()` Gives error unable to locate element.

Comment: Anything else I should try ?

Comment: can you post the URL?

Comment: You wont have access to the URL ,

Comment: Is ID attribute constant? Do you see the same `"J22_MNQ_LOP_V1WR_SEARCH_BTN"` after page refresh?

Comment: yup I see the same after page refresh

Comment: Then check whether `table` located inside an `iframe`/`frame`

Comment: I see Iframe reference in the Html code but not near the mentioned table.
If its embedded in iframe how will it be different ?

Comment: You should check **all** ancestors on **all** levels till the root node. If `table` is inside an `iframe` you will not be able to find elements inside it without switching to DOM of `iframe`

Comment: @Andersson can you provide me some reference so that I can go through on how to work on the elements under iframe in selenium python.
As far as I checked there are references of Iframe but the table doesn't exist inside it.

Comment: @vanishka , you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44187909/python-selenium-and-captcha/44188065#44188065)

Comment: Thanks, Andersson, I found that it belongs to an Iframe from outer html.
is this the default statement I need to put in order to find the `search` button '//iframe[contains(@src, "Search"]`

Comment: Iframe attributes are not constant. Share HTML for iframe

Comment: @Andersson Which Html do you need , the page source or frame source.
Is there any way to traceback and verify the xpath id that I should use in iframe ?

Comment: Just add HTML for `iframe` opening tag. Something like `<iframe name="iframe_name" src="/iframe/source">`

Comment: @Andersson Added iframe Html

Comment: So, this button *is* inside of an iframe? Also, you added a snippet of an <iframe> as well as a <frame>. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* to click on the **Search** button you have to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following line of code :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='th-sa-tb-bt']/span[@class='th-bt-up']/a[@class='th-bt th-bt-text-em']/span[@class='th-bt-span']/b[@class='th-bt-b']"))).click()
```

Comment: Same Timeout exception

Answer (score 0):

First: using a time.sleep followed by a WebdriverWait completely nullifies the value of the WebdriverWait. I might even  describe it as low-grade evil.

As for your issue - I am not yet convinced the element is there to be found. Can you go to the console in your browser dev tools and type $x('YOUR_XPATH_HERE'), press enter and tell me if it returns the expected element? If not, and you see the element on the page, the issue is with your locator.

If you see the element but you can't find it with a known-good locator, look for an iframe or other element that could be grabbing your focus. This may require webdriver.switch_to()

Comment: No it returns an empty element like this `[]` and when I expand it it shows `length:0` upon expansion `--proto__: Array(0)` further expansion of this shows lot of values like `AttributeExistsInArray` etc ..

Comment: Then your locator is not correct. Please refer to my comment on the below answer where I give you two xpaths to try.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'th-') and contains(text(), 'Search')]")
element.click()
```

If this returns `Unable to locate element`, use this first:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'th-') and contains(text(), 'Search')]"))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

## Switch to the frame before interacting

Selenium can only interact with a single document at a time. If the element you desire is located in a frame, you will need to “switch to” that frame before searching or clicking:

```py
iframe = driver.find_element_by_name("UiApplicationFrame")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Search")
    element.click()
finally:
    driver.switch_to.default_content
```

### P.S. Search like a human

Notice that my answer searches for the element in a different way.

While searching by ID may work for now, it might not always. The implementation of the page could easily change, breaking your script.

To be more resilient against such change, search like a human would: by looking for an interactive element by its text.

## Bonus: Simplify with Capybara

This can be further simplified by using [capybara-py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/capybara-py), which provides a helpful layer atop Selenium:

```py
with page.frame("UiApplicationFrame"):
    page.click_link("Search")
```

In addition to simplifying the work of finding and switching into and out of frames, Capybara provides helpers, such as `click_link`, for performing common interactions with semantic, accessible HTML elements. It also synchronizes everything, e.g., by retrying if the link is not yet visible or not yet clickable.

Answer (score -1):

This had been the same issue with selenium which I too faced, but you can workaround it with something like this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="J22_MNQ_LOP_V1WR_SEARCH_BTN"]'))
)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="J22_MNQ_LOP_V1WR_SEARCH_BTN"]').click()
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: It gives me the same `Timeout exception`

Comment: @vanishka: I checked from my end and it worked fine as expected. I believe you are using some old configuration i.e. Chrome browser or selenium. Can you check and confirm.

Comment: @learner8269 , what is the point of your approach? IMHO it makes no sense to find the same element twice

Comment: @andersson : You are right but if sometimes element goes stale, which might be the case we need to apply this workaround as I faced this issue before too. Add something if you have any suggestions to give.

Comment: I can hardly believe that element can become stale after you find it once and your second search will solve the issue... I'm afraid that your suggestion is wrong

Comment: I am using latest version of chrome, chrome driver  & selenium, Do you feel downgrading to old version will work ?

Comment: @vanishka , Deffinitely NO

Comment: I too feel the same, thanks for clarifying Andersson

Comment: Why are you using the id of what looks like a javascript object? Just look for the `a` element with that text and click it.

Comment: `"//a[contains(text(), 'Search')]"` should get you there. If not, `"//b[contains(text(), 'Search')]/../.."` will get you your `a` and you can click that.

Comment: @Aphid I have pasted the Iframe content can you help.