# How Can I Make a Web Scraper That Keeps Scraping Data even when the PC is offline using SELENIUM Python

Tags: python, selenium, hcaptcha

So I have been Working on a Web scraper that scrapes data from discord.

For this I used selenium python. So I want it to keep scraping data even when my Computer is offline.

So after a little research I found that I can use repl.it and uptime bot.

repl.it to run the script on the web and uptime bot to ping it in every 5 minutes.

But when I ran the script on repl.it it opened a small chromium window
which was good for that time[image: the ref. img.]
and in that it was prompting the hcaptcha

[image: hcaptcha]

and here is where the problem began.

I tried Hard to find the class name of the checkbox of the hcaptcha and eventually found it but, then it asked me for selecting the pictures.

[image]

there were many solutions for recaptcha but none for hcaptcha.

So I searched it every where but couldn't find a solution that could satisfy my problem

Solutions Iam Looking for the problem:-

1.Any other platform or way i can run my script forever(of course which are not commerical and paid like aws, microsoft and all....)

2.and way to sort that hcaptcha problem (because where ever I find they have a answer for recaptcha not hcaptcha)

Links, Code, And resources I referred while making the project and looking for the solution

1.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=As-_hfZUyIs(to bypass recaptcha)

2.https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-easily-bypass-recaptchav2-with-selenium-7f7a9a44fa9e

3.https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-handle-captcha-in-selenium

4.https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/efeaxy/captcha_using_selenium_in_python/

5.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44187909/python-selenium-and-captcha

6.https://github.com/dessant/buster(recaptch buster)

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1: You could fit the script into Repl.it look [here](https://replit.com/talk/ask/Can-I-use-selenium/11566) and use a replit auto pinger which pings the service every 5 minutes to keep your project alive.

Issue 2: There is a tampermonkey extention, [here](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/425854-hcaptcha-solver-automatically-solves-hcaptcha-in-browser) and what you could do is create a profile in chrome/any browser (I perfer firefox) and install greasemonkey, install the script, and then check if the captcha element exists and if it does, wait for 40 seconds. After that the captcha should solve by itself. There's also [this](https://github.com/avengy/hcaptcha-bypass-discord) repo on github if you're interested in a different method of bypassing hCaptcha.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you sir
I Had planned to use the uptime bot which would ping it

Comment: But actually what I want is that it bypasses the captcha in the repl.it chromium window